# Case wise delete of values inside cor() in R

Tags: r, correlation, ordinals

Consider the following survey data:

```
data <- replicate(10 ,sample(c(1,2,3,4), 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

`V1:V9` are variables where `1 = "Good"`, `2 = "Okey"` and `3 = "Not Good"` and `4 = "Don't know"` while `V10` is an ordinal variable where `1 = "Good"`, `2 = "Not good"`, `3 = "Don't know"` and `4 = "Don't want to answer"`.

I am interested in calculating a simple correlation matrix using `cor()` on these variables. However, I only want to calculate it between the values that actually mean something. That is, `1,2,3` for `V1:V9` and `1,2` for `V10`.

In other words, I want a case wise delete of any value `> 3` for `V1:V9` and the same for any values `> 2` for `V10` within the `cor()` function.

This would be similar to the use argument?

The only way I have managed to solve this is by mutating these values as NA.

```
library("dplyr")
data_test <- data_test %>%
      mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. > 3, NA, .)), -V10) %>%
      mutate(ifelse(V10 > 2, NA, V10))

cor(data_test, use = "complete.obs")
```

But is there a better way that does not necessarily rely on modifying the data.

*PS. There are, of course, more adequate ways of calculating correlation between ordinal variables.*

Comment: Relevant posts: [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007) and [here](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was more simple than I thought.

As @zx8754 points out you should be careful when choosing correlation method for categorical variables.

Anyways, you just change `use = "pairwise.complete.obs"` in `cor()`

However, you still need to mutate 4 to `NA`.